# Lambda calculus as set-theoretic operations

Tags: set-theory, lambda-calculus

It is possible to interpret typed lambda calculus a-la Church as logical operations (because of Curry-Howard correspondence). Also, there is a isomorphism between logical and set-theoretic operations. So, is it possible to direct interpret lambda application as union of sets, and lambda abstraction as subset relation or something like this? Which set-theoretic operations corresponds to lambda application and abstraction?